# css support view-slideshow right to left

Tags: css, drupal, themes

I want to support right to left transition of images in my slideshow.
My CSS view slideshow code in style.css:

```
$.block-slideshow .view-content {
position:relative;
background:red;
padding: 2px 5px 5px 7px;
}
.block-slideshow .views_slideshow_thumbnailhover_main img {
float: left;
}
.block-slideshow .views-slideshow-controls-bottom {
 position:absolute; 
 top:5px;
 right:5px; 
 list-style:none; 
 padding:0;
 margin:0; 
 width:310px;
z-index:100;
}
.block-slideshow .views_slideshow_thumbnailhover_div_breakout_teaser {
 padding:5px 10px 0 45px;
 margin:0;  
 background:#6A99AD url(../images/slideshow-nav-bullet.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
 height:41px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
}
.block-slideshow .views_slideshow_thumbnailhover_div_breakout_teaser:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.block-slideshow .views-slideshow-controls-bottom .activeSlide {
 background:#024D76 url(../images/slideshow-nav-bullet.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
list-style: disc;
}
.block-slideshow .view-slideshow .views-field-title {
 color:#FFF;
font-size:120%;
font-weight:bold;
}
.block-slideshow .view-slideshow .views-field-body {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:100%;
}
.block-slideshow .view-slideshow .views-field-body p {
 margin:0!important;
 }
```

please visit this link
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMdc1.jpg

Please Guide me
I want to support right to left transitions in view slideshow.
style-rtl:?

please visit this link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s23XY.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in style-rtl.css]

```
$.block-slideshow .views-slideshow-controls-bottom {
 position:absolute; 
 top:5px;
 right:605px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the floating, replace "left" with "right" and vica versa

```
.block-slideshow .views_slideshow_thumbnailhover_main img {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: i added this code in style-rtl.css but not correct.not changing

Comment: your style-rtl.css must be run after main css. is it comes after main.css?

Comment: give the link to that page. I can't say what to do without seeing the code

Comment: In that case I can say only the logic - find the image container block and give him "float:right", then find the navigation container block and make it "float:left". that is all